# CSV files being locked after python program compiled with pyinstaller

Tags: python, locking, pyinstaller

I have generated a snippet of code using pycharm, in the pycharm environment the programme works perfectly. In essence it opens a csv, undertakes various data updates on the csv and then pushes the data to FTP.

Running the application in Pycharm everything works as it should. However when I compile the application in pyinstaller and run the EXE the program locks the csv files so they cannot be deleted until a reboot takes place

Any suggestions ?

Tried using With Open along with multiple other options, even tried deleting the file within the python code during execution of the program, in pycharm files were deleted - in the executable this did not happen and the files were locked

Comment: How do you read your csv files in the python program?

Comment: Hi Marcelo - with open('w:\paul b\shipup\shipup.csv', encoding='utf-8') as f :
    df = pd.read_csv(f)